# Why is wordpress is showing HTML instead of regular text wysiwyg editor?

Tags: wordpress, text, wysiwyg, edit

When I'm trying to use a text blok editor in Wordpress and click the wysiwyg, you see white html code the same as if you click on text. Where can I change this back to normal?

Thanks in advance.

Tijs Luitse

Comment: There's a setting under User Options to turn on/off the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: This question is not about which editors are available or default.  If it's the same bug I'm having, when you click Update, the Visual editor displays the HTML source that should be in the Text editor and the Text editor shows the HTML source with, e.g. <b> encoded as &lt;b&gt;.

Answer (score 1):

In the Dashboard, navigate to:

```
Users > Your Profile > Personal Options > Uncheck "Disable the visual editor..."
```

No need to edit **functions.php**.

Answer (score 0):

> When I'm in the Wysiwyg I cannot see the text because it is white

Sounds like your theme may be including a stylesheet to change the look of the visual editor (themes often do this so you'll see your content as it will be displayed on the front-end, with the correct fonts etc). Check for an editor.css or similarly named file, or for the function `add_editor_style()` used somewhere in your functions.php or other theme files.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why WordPress might be showing HTML instead of the regular text editor.

**- You have disabled the visual editor:** Go to Users > Your Profile > Personal Options and uncheck the box next to "Disable the visual editor when writing.

**- You are using a plugin that is overriding the visual editor:**
To check, try disabling the plugin and see if the visual editor reappears.

**- There is a problem with your theme:**
To check, try switching to a different theme and see if the visual editor works properly.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to your theme's functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', create_function('', 'return "tinymce";') );
```

It should make the "visual" editor the default.